# JavaScript Array interview question; couldn't find the bug

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration

A friend of mine was asked the question below during a live interview and was given 4 minutes to answer it.

QUESTION:
Without opening any other browser or using code editor, analyze the code below and give your verdict if it is correct and good to go, if not, debug the code and explain your answer.

```
const weekDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

for (let i = 0; i < weekDays.length; i++){
    if (i === 'Wednesday'){
        console.log('Today is Wednesday, join board meeting by 10:00am');
        continue;
    }
    if (i === 'Saturday'){
        console.log("Today is Saturday, weekend is great!");
        break;
    }
    console.log(weekDays[i]);
}
```

Comment: What is considered *"correct and good to go"*?

Comment: @Spectric, as I mentioned, the question was a live session and just the code was live at the browser while the person interviewing gave instructions and asked the question, as explained by my friend who gave me the question after the interview.

Answer (score 3):

Just take a [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), because the array could have days in different order or start.

And for really good code, take a semantic name `day` instead of `i`.

```js
const weekDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

for (const i of weekDays) {
    if (i === 'Wednesday') {
        console.log('Today is Wednesday, join board meeting by 10:00am');
        continue;
    }
    if (i === 'Saturday') {
        console.log("Today is Saturday, weekend is great!");
        break;
    }
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you provided your own answer, but this code could easily be cleaned up further to reduce bugs:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < weekDays.length; i++) {
    if (i === 3) {
        console.log('Today is Wednesday, join board meeting by 10:00am');
    } else if (i === 6) {
        console.log("Today is Saturday, weekend is great!");
    } else {
        console.log(weekDays[i]);
    }
}
```

Still not a fan of the magic numbers. Perhaps `i === Day.Wednesday` or `weekDays[i] === Day.Wednesday` depending on what's expected to change.